# Geowebcache 900913

Tags: geowebcache

I am trying to create a wms tile cache in 900913 projection using Geoserver's Geowebcache extension. My data is  in a PostgreSQL database in 4326 projection. Do I have to reproject my data to 900913(a.k.a. 3857) prior to seeding my tile layer in 900913?

Answer (score 2):

No, but it will be faster if you do. And please use 3857 instead of 900913 which has been deprecated for a while now.

Comment: GeoServer's integrated GWC has a predefined gridset EPSG:900913 but not EPSG:3857 gridset. Perhaps GWC/GeoServer projects could show good example here.

Comment: feel free to submit a pull request to fix it